# python class with many attributes

Tags: python, class

I am trying to create a class with lots of attributes (about 10). Is there a prettier (more Pythonic) way to initiate the class than:

```
class myClass:
def __init__(self,atributeA,atributeB,atributeC)
   self.atributeA=atributeA
   self.atributeB=atributeB
   self.atributeC=atributeC
```

and is there a better way to make a class instance than

```
thisInstance=myClass(valueA,valueB,valueC)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use keyword arguments. It would be as simple as:

```
thisInstance=myClass(atributeA=valueA, atributeB=valueB, atributeC=valueC)
```

One of the advantages of this is that you can pass the values in any order you want.

You don't even have to modify the class definition at all.

Comment: I like this solution for creating the class instance. I'm not sure it helps for setting the attributes within the class.

Comment: Another advantage is that you don't accidentally put the wrong value into a variable because you switched the order when you called the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dirty method too:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


d = {"attributeA": "a", "attributeB": "b"}
c = MyClass(**d)
```

Note though, that any property within the dict that has the same name as an important property of your class will overwrite that important property.

Edit:
In case it's not understood, by dirty I mean don't do this unless you have a fantastic reason, and your class can not be misused by other people!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following for the initialisation.

```
def __init__(self, attributeA, attributeB, attributeC)
    vars(self).update(locals())
```

Comment: Could you only add a subset of locals? Sort of like: `vars(self).update(locals() in validInputsList)`

Comment: Yes: `vars(self).update( subset(locals(),validInputsList))`
with `subset` via [link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/115417-subset-of-a-dictionary/)

Comment: Wow, this was exactly what I was looking for! I find it very inelegant to assign dozens of arguments to the object when we know all of them have to be assigned without any modification

Answer (score 0):

you could use *args or **kwargs and send a tuple or dictionary with your parameters

Comment: That... could be messy. You have to ensure you actually got as many parameters as you want, you have to take them from the tuple.... in the case of variable keyword arguments you have to ensure the keys are in there, etc. Not a good idea.